# Using Eloquent in Codeigniter, I'm having trouble setting up relationships

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, eloquent

I followed [this tutorial](http://jamieonsoftware.com/post/90299647695/using-eloquent-orm-inside-codeigniter-with-added) to get Laravel's Eloquent running inside an existing Codeigniter project and everything worked fine until I attemped to use Eloquent's relationships. Here's my offending code:

```
class Announcement_model extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'announcements';
    public function game() {
        $this->load->model('game_model');
        return $this->belongsTo('Game_model', 'game_id');
    }
}

class Game_model extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'games';    
}
```

And the controller:

```
class Api_announcement extends REST_Controller {
    ...
    public function index_get() {
        $response = Announcement_model::with('game')->get();
        $this->response(array('error'=> false, 'response' => $response), 200);
    }
}
```

I'm running into this error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation' in myproject\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php:2695
Stack trace:
#0 myproject\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php(2665): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;getRelationshipFromMethod('load')
#1 myproject\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php(2607): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;getRelationValue('load')
#2 myproject\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php(3325): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;getAttribute('load')
#3 myproject\application\models\announcement_model.php(11): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model-&gt;__get('load')
#4 myproject\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Builder.php(477): Announcement_model-&gt;game()
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder-&gt;Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
#6  in 
<b>myproject\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php</b> on line 
<b>2695</b>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked up and down for a solution but nothing works.

Comment: It was initially returning `return $this->belongsTo('Game_model', 'game_id')->select(array('name'));` but that was after many tries with `$this->belongsTo('Game_model', 'game_id')`. I realize it would be best, for clarity, if I removed the alteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->belongsTo('Game_model', 'game_id')->select(array('name'));
```

Returns in array, but no Relation. You need this:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Game_model', 'game_id');
```

Comment: Still does not work. At first I tried `belongsTo` like you said, then added the `->select` in the hopes it would work. I just tried again without it and got the same error.

Comment: But why do you load the model `game_load` in the relationship? you don't need it there.

Comment: Just to load the class, I'm not using an autoloader for that.